# Ubuntu openstack installation help

Tags: server, juju, openstack, cloud

I am trying to follow below mentioned URL and install multi-node mode

https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#single-multi-large-cluster

I followed exact steps for installation, after providing this command "sunbeam cluster bootstrap --role control --role compute --role storage "
juju bootstrapping will start which never ends the installation, please help me to resolve this issue